# How do export a React component with related "child" components

Tags: reactjs

I've seen some libraries supporting the ability to do things like

```html
<Table>
    <Table.Row>This would replace importing a component called TableRow separately.</Table.Row>
</Table>
```

Not sure if it's bad practice or not but was wondering how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design pattern known as Compound Components. You can make the sub-components static members of the outer class.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Row = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

class Table extends Component {
  static Row = Row;

  render() {
    const { children, ...props } = this.props;
    return <div {...props}>{children}</div>;
  }
}

Table.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.oneOf([Row])
    })
  )
};

export default Table;
```

Usage

```
import Table from "./Table";

...

<Table>
  <Table.Row>I'm a compound Row component!!</Table.Row>
  <Table.Row>I'm another compound Row component!!</Table.Row>
  <div>I'll throw a react proptype warning</div>
</Table>
```

[image: Edit Compound component]

> How can we achieve this with function components?

It is nearly the same, but just add the compounded component as a property to the root component. If `Table` is a function component then to add the `Row` component to it, `Table.Row = Row;`. With class components falling out of favor in React this is the preferred pattern.

```
const Row = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

const Table = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div {...props}>{children}</div>
);

Table.Row = Row;

export default Table;
```

Comment: how can we achieve this with functional components?

Comment: @MehrdadShokri If `Table` is a function component then just add the compounded components as a property of `Table`, i.e. `Table.Row = Row`. See https://codesandbox.io/s/compound-component-forked-6u4lq?file=/src/Table.jsx

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding the child component to the parent component object and export the parent. Not exactly bad practice but it can help a lot with keeping components organized.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Row = ({children}) => <span>{children}</span>;

const Table = ({children}) => <>{children}</>;

Table.Row = Row;

export default Table;
```